# Why the positions of the elements change on the page after a postback?

Tags: asp.net, css, postback

Did you have such an experience:

I have an asp.net page with couple of div elements on my page. Some of them are floating left and some are separated with `<br />` elements.

When I put a button which just post-backs and click that, I see that some divs (which were floated to left before) are repositioned to a new line.

Any idea about possible reasons?

thanks,

Comment: It would help to post a link to the problematic page or give us some source code to have a look at. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using Clearfix or Clear:both, or possibly you have it setup correctly on the first page but not on the postback?